# Why should I use tuples when doing hops?

Tags: sesam

I've been told that I should use tuples instead of multiple eq-s when doing hops whenever possible. From the documentation:

> This function is a good choice when you need to do joins on composite keys.

Could someone explain why this is a good choice?